# Excellent test automation framework for WPF RadControls automation

Tags: c#, automation, telerik, ui-automation

I am looking for a test automation framework with simple and robust API for C# language. There is an application that is developed using WPF and RadControls (Telerik). Unfortunately, Coded UI doesn't support RadControls because for most of them AutomationPeer is not implemented.   Does anyone know appropriate framework that support general WPF and RadControls controls?

Here is a list of RadControls:

1. RadDatePicker;
2. RadMaskedTextBox;
3. RadGridView;
4. RadTreeView;
5. RadTreeListView;
6. RadOutlookBar;
7. RadTimePicker;
8. RadComboBox;
9. RadBusyIndicator;
10. RadTileView;
11. RadChart;
12. RadCalendar;
13. RadColorPicker;
14. RadProgressBar.

I was thinking about several workarounds (AutomationPeer implementation in inherited RadControls, IronPython injection on the form etc.), but I do want to find appropriate tool and do not focus on them.

Thank you in advance.

Regards, Stas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a purely web application, Telerik's own testing suite might fit your needs. http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/